# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I was adding the Facebook SDK to my project when I started building gradle build I recieves this message "Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+" I´ve looked in build.gradle and it looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/zMSwMz9Q

From what I can see that should be able to get that plugin. I´ve cleaned and refreshed all I can but I keep getting that error. And yes, SDK is up to date.

Comment: try adding support library from project structure.

Comment: The support libraries are pulled from the local Android SDK maven repository, not any online repository, so you have to make sure you have the support library installed in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Harry - how would that be done in eclipse?
Tenfour04 - It is installed and up to date